# .each() terminar quando a div for fechada

Tags: jquery, foreach

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho divs que possuem uma quantidade dinâmica de divs dentro.

```
<div class="grid-f">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-f">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-f">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
</div>
```

Percorro as colunas com o .each() e adiciono classes a cada 3 divs

```
$('.col-4').each(function(index,value){
        if((index%3)==0){
            $(this).addClass('margin-r');
        } else if ((index%3)==1) {
            $(this).addClass('margin-lr');
        }
        else if ((index%3)==2) {
            $(this).addClass('margin-l');
        }
    });
```

Porém o que eu queria era que o .each() parasse quando fechasse a primeira `grid-f` no exemplo dado, porque quando chega na primeira `col-4` do segundo `grid-f` ele adiciona a classe errada pois entende que está no index 4 e não no 0 como eu queria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisará utilizar 2 `.each` para obter o resultado esperado.

```
$('.grid-f).each(function(index,value){
     jQuery(this).find('.col-4').each(function(index,value) {
        if((index%3)==0){
            $(this).addClass('margin-r');
        } else if ((index%3)==1) {
            $(this).addClass('margin-lr');
        }
        else if ((index%3)==2) {
            $(this).addClass('margin-l');
        }
     }
});
```

O problema que você relata ocorre porque o seletor `col-4` irá selecionar todos os elementos sem distinção de seus containers. Com dois laços, você percorrerá cada `grid-f` separadamente.